# SPARQL Update isin't working with Jena JDBC and Jena RDFConnection, for RDF data

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, turtle-rdf

I have following data in a graph (named as "data.n3" or "data.ttl", I tried with both the extensions) :-

```
# Default graph
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix ns: <http://example.org/ns#> .

<http://example/book1> ns:price 42 .
```

I tried the following 2 code snippets :-

**Code 1**

```
import org.apache.jena.query.Dataset;
import org.apache.jena.query.DatasetFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnection;
import org.apache.jena.rdfconnection.RDFConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.jena.system.Txn;

public class DataWriting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dataset ds = DatasetFactory.create();
        try (RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(ds);) {
            conn.load("data.ttl") ;
            conn.update("PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>\r\n" + 
            "INSERT DATA\r\n" + 
            "{ \r\n" + 
            "  <http://example/book1> dc:title \"A new book\" ;\r\n" + 
            "                         dc:creator \"A.N.Other\" .\r\n" + 
            "}") ;
            conn.put("data.n3");
            conn.commit();
            }) ;
        }
    }
}
```

**Code 2**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.jena.jdbc.mem.MemDriver;

public class DataWriting {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            MemDriver.register();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jena:mem:dataset=data.ttl");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>\r\n" + 
                    "INSERT DATA\r\n" + 
                    "{ \r\n" + 
                    "  <http://example/book1> dc:title \"A new book\" ;\r\n" + 
                    "                         dc:creator \"A.N.Other\" .\r\n" + 
                    "}");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("SQL Error - " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The expectation is the data in the file "data.n3" or "data.ttl" to become the following :-

```
# Default graph
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix ns: <http://example.org/ns#> .

<http://example/book1> ns:price 42 .
<http://example/book1> dc:title "A new book" .
<http://example/book1> dc:creator "A.N.Other" .
```

However, this is not actually happening after the execution of any of the above 2 Java programs. Am I missing something or doing anything incorrectly ?

Comment: Which triple store are you using? Is the triple store throwing any exceptions?

Comment: I am using a ttl/n3 file as in-memory data. I haven't got any exception. My guess is that the insert query executes but somehow the data doesn't gets saved back to the file for some reason ??

Comment: No, nothing will be written to the file. It is loaded in-memory, thus, you are updating just the in-memory data nothing more, nothing less. you need to write the data back to disk.

Comment: Hi @ASKW, I have tried using "conn.put("data.n3");" (updated in the code above), which was unable to write back to disk. May I know how should I write back to the disk with any of the 2 programs please ?

Comment: Easiest way should be using the method `ds.getDefaultModel().write(...)`

Comment: It worked. But it is giving me RDF XML format. Any way to write the content in original format please ?

Comment: the `write` method is overloaded, just use the one which takes the language as argument, or use `RDFDataMgr.write(OutputStream, Dataset, Lang)` with the dataset given or the model given as second argument and `Lang.NTRIPLES` (or whatever you need) as third argument

Comment: Thanks @AKSW, the data got inserted. But I also noticed the following (not for the example given above) :-

1. For named graph, GRAPH keyword is used in query, the program executed, but no update happened.
2. For DELETE WHERE, I got the exception :- Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 4, col: 1 ] Out of place: [KEYWORD:DELETE]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `DELETE {} WHERE {}`? I mean, you have to define the quad pattern that has to be deleted as well, not only the pattern that matches. Or maybe you should show the whole query, not just a stub.

Comment: Correct. 2 of the queries that didn't work are in the following comments :-

Comment: WITH <http://example/addresses>
DELETE { ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' }
INSERT { ?person foaf:givenName 'William' }
WHERE
{ ?person foaf:givenName 'Bill' }

Comment: WITH <example/addresses>; DELETE { ?person ?property ?value } WHERE { ?person ?property ?value ; foaf:givenName 'Fred' }

Comment: Another problem is that if there are 2 graphs, and I make an operation like "MOVE", how to capture the modifications to both graphs ? I was able to get result for only 1 of those 2.